# Difference between Fermi and Riemann normal coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, definition, geodesics, equivalence-principle

1. What is the difference between [Fermi normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates) and [Riemann normal coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates)?
2. Which one of them is related to the vanishing of the Christoffel symbols?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a future-directed timelike curve $\gamma= \gamma(\tau)$, $\tau$ being the proper time along $\gamma$ in the spacetime $M$. Assume that   $p = \gamma(0)$ is the initial point of $\gamma$.

**Fermi coordinates** adapted to $\gamma$ are constructed this way.

Consider an orthonormal  basis of $T_pM$ with $e_0$ parallel to $\dot{\gamma}$.

Transport the basis $\{e_a\}_{a=0,1,2,3}$ along $\gamma= \gamma(\tau)$ making use of **Fermi-Walker's transport**. The basis  $\{e_a(\tau)\}_{a=0,1,2,3}$  at each point $\gamma(\tau)$ is still orthonormal with 
$e_0(\tau)$ parallel to $\dot{\gamma}(\tau)$ and is **non-rotated** (in a precise sense related to the decomposition of Lorentz transformations into pure transformations and rotations) with respect to the initial basis, this is the physical meaning of Fermi-Walker's transport.

Finally construct a coordinate system in a open tube $T$, a  neighbourhood of $\gamma$, emitting all spacelike geodesics through $\gamma(\tau)$ with initial tangent vector $\sum_{i=1}^3 v^i e_i(\tau)$, for every $\tau$.

A point $q\in T$ has coordinates 
$\tau(q), v^1(q), v^2(q), v^3(q)$ where $\sum_{i=1}^3 v^i(q) e_i(\tau(q))$ is the only vector whose associated geodesic reaches $q$ for the value of its parameter $s=1$ and $\tau(q)$ is the only time along $\gamma$ for that this geodesic reaching $q$ exists.

If $\gamma$ itself is a geodesic, then Fermi-Walker's transport becomes the standard **parallel transport** and Fermi's coordinates become standard **Riemannian coordinates** adapted to $\gamma$. In this case, using these coordinates in a neighbourhood $T$ of $\gamma$, we have  $\Gamma_{ab}^c =0$ exactly on $\gamma$.  This property is **not** valid for Fermi's coordinates however when $\gamma$ is not a geodesic.

A modern reference on the subject is http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9402010 where also *rotating* coordinates are discussed.

Comment: I am confused by answer. Because wiki said that Fermi coordinate is adapted to timelike geodesics $\gamma$ and you said that when $\gamma$ is a geodesic then it becomes the Riemann coordinate. Then they are the same thing by your answer and wikipedia's definition. I think Fermi coordinate is a generalization of Riemann coordinate such that the Christoffel symbol vanishes not only at a point but along the whole geodesic.  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates

Comment: In my answer I refer to Riemannian coordinates **adapted** to $\gamma$ which means that the Christoffel symbols vanishes along the curve (it must be a geodesics). This type of coordinates is known since long time before relativity and Fermi's work!  Fermi coordinates instead are strictly related to relativity and concern the transport of a non-rotating frame along a timelike curve, that is another idea with some overlap with that of Riemannian coordinates. My impression on the wikipedia page is that it is written into a bit sloppy way.

Comment: I also think  that there  are different viewpoints on the terminology in the literature.

Comment: @ValterMoretti nice reference! Did you notice that the author keeps calling Enrico Fermi as M. Fermi?  :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Riemann normal coordinates** (or just **normal coordinates** for short) are the "granddaddy" of the different normal coordinate constructions: 
The Riemann normal cordinate system is a system of local coordinates that is errected around a *single point* of the manifold (in General Relativity, with its space-time manifold, a point is usually called an *event*).

As coordinate lines, one takes *all* the geodesics (time-like, null, and space-like alike ;-) ) that intersect this point. The coordinate transformation from the Riemann coordinates to the (arbitrary) background coordinates then follows from a Taylor-series solution ansatz of the corresponding geodesic equation. Its Taylor coefficients can be written in terms of partial derivatives of the Christoffel symbols.
One then demands that -- as seen from the Riemann normal coordinate system -- theese geodesics all look like straight lines, i.e. that they be (albeit unphysical) *local inertial coordinates*. If one now take the above coordinate transformation in Riemann coordinates, one finds that for this, all quadratic and higher Taylor coefficients must vanish *in Riemann coordinates*. The 1st-order Taylor coefficient is given by the Christoffel symbols,  the 2nd-order one by its 1st partial derivative, and so on. This vanishing of the Taylor coefficients then yields the *coordinate conditions* of the Riemann normal coord. system:  The Christoffel symbols and all their higher (symmetrised) derivatives vanish.

**Fermi normal coordinates** are a slight extension of the construction of Riemann normal coordinates in order to have a local inertial coord. system that is able to describe also physical observers, who always follow time-like world-lines (i.e., they will always move through space-time along their local time-like directions even when they are stationary).

With Fermi coordinates, one expands *not only about a single point*, *but along a whole time-like curve*, which is then the world-line of some observer. This is the crucial difference between Riemann and Fermi normal coordinates. In Fermi coordinates, one thus performs a spacial-only (i.e. 3-dimensional) Riemann coordinate expansion, outwards from and orthogonal to the central world-line, i.e. only along the space-like geodesics that intersect the world-line orthogonally (they are orthogonal to the four-velocity, which is the tangent of the central world-line).

So, since Fermi coordinates are based on (a continuous family of spacial-only) Riemann coordinates, they both "have" vansihing Christoffel symbols. More precisely: in Riemann coordinates, the Christoffel symbols vanish, along with all their first and higher (symmetrised) partial derivatives.

In Fermi coordinates, since they involve spacial-only Riemann expansions, only the spacial (lower indices) Christoffel symbols vanish. Correspondingly, at the second and higher orders of the expansion, it is also their totally symmetric first and higher *spacial* partial derivatives, that are zero.

Now, wether the *non-spacial* part of the Christoffel symbols also vanishes, depends on wether the central world-line of the construction is also a geodesic, or not.

If it is a geodesic, then also the non-spacial Christoffels vanish (in this case its tangent, i.e. the four-velocity, is parallel transported and the observer following that geodesic world-line is inertial, or freely falling). 
Conversely, if it is not a geodesic (which means that the observer following the world-line is non-inertial, i.e. he is accelerated and/or his spacial basis vectors are rotating), then the non-spacial Christoffels will not vanish, since they are related to his four-acceleration and rotation.