# Gravity without force of gravity. What does it mean?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, metric-tensor, geodesics

As we know, the gravitation force in General Relativity is the semblant phenomenon. Let's look at this phenomenon in more detail.

---

### A brief preface

---

From the Landau-Lifshitz "Volume 2. The Classical Theory of fields" (LL2)(Problem 1 in §88), we can see the equation of motion (EOM) and an expression for gravitation force (we put $c=1$):

EOM(also known as $\frac{dp}{dt} =F$ or $ma = F$) :
\begin{equation}
    \sqrt{1-v^2} \frac{d}{ds}\frac{v^{\alpha}}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} + \lambda^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}\frac{mv^{\beta}v^{\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} = f^{\alpha}
\end{equation}

Gravitation force (also known as $F = G\frac{mM}{r^2}$):
\begin{equation}
    f_{\alpha} = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}\left[ -\frac{\partial \ln\sqrt{h}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} + \sqrt{h} \left(\frac{\partial g_{\beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} - \frac{\partial g_{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}\right){v^{\beta}}\right]
\end{equation}
where $h = g_{00}$, $g_{\alpha} = -\frac{g_{0\alpha}}{g_{00}}$.

As one can see, the *origin of gravitation force in GR is mostly due to the curvature of time*, because it depend on component of metrics $g_{00}$.
And this force in LL2 expressed in 3-vector form, which looks similar to Lorentz force:
\begin{equation}\label{3Force}
 \vec{F} = \frac{m}{\sqrt{1-v^2}} \left( -\vec\nabla\ln\sqrt{h} + \left[\vec{v}\times\left[ \sqrt{h}\vec\nabla\times\vec{g}\right] \right] \right),
\end{equation}

Now consider an EOM. The RHS of EOM consists of two terms. The second term contains spatial Cristoffel symbols $\lambda^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}$ which is also depend on metrics.

---

## Attempts to ask a question

---

Lets consider some kind of spherical-symmetric metrics (now we are not interested in the distribution of matter that caused it):

$$ds^2 = dt^2 - \frac{dr^2}{1-\frac{2M}{r}} - r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2).$$

Nonzero  components of $\Gamma^i_{jk}$:
\begin{align}
\Gamma^r_{rr} &= -\frac{M}{r^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}},\\
\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta} &= 2M - r\\ 
\Gamma^r_{\phi\phi} &= (2M - r)\sin^2\theta\\ 
\Gamma^{\theta}_{r\theta} &= \Gamma^{\phi}_{r\phi} = \frac1r\\
\Gamma^{\theta}_{\phi\phi} &= -\sin\theta\cos\theta \\
\Gamma^{\phi}_{\theta\phi} &= \cot\theta,
\end{align}
$\Gamma\text{'s} = \lambda\text{'s}$.
The Riemann Tensor nonzero components:
\begin{align}
 R_{r\theta r\theta} & = \frac{M}{r}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}} \\
 R_{r\phi r\phi} & = \frac{M}{r}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{1-\frac{2M}{r}} \\
 R_{\theta\phi\theta\phi} &= - 2Mr\sin^2\theta
\end{align}
This metrics is only spattialy curved.

Scalar curvature $R = 0$.

According to gravitation force expression, we conclude there is no force $f_{\alpha} = 0$ in such metrics. Then (in case $\theta =\frac\pi 2$, $\frac{d^2\theta}{ds^2} = 0$) the EOM has the simple form:

\begin{align}
 \frac{d^2r}{ds^2} &= \frac{M}{r^2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2M}{r}}\frac{(v^r)^2}{1-v^2} +  (r-2M)\frac{(v^{\phi})^2}{1-v^2}\\
 \frac{d^2\phi}{ds^2} &=  \frac1r \frac{v^r v^{\phi}}{1-v^2}.
\end{align}

Due to nonzero values of $\lambda^{\alpha}_{\beta\gamma}$ in EOM, the geodesics are not straight lines in such metrics. If particle has zero initial velocity, then will be no force of attraction to the origin.

But, if the particle has the radial velocity, then it will be attract to the origin. Thus, we have the gravity without force of gravity.

How to correctly judge the reality of gravity, by the existence of force $f_{\alpha}$ or by the geodesics deviation? What is the meaning of the force of gravity in LL2?

Comment: The $g_{00}$ term is not zero in your spherically symmetric metric there since there is a term proportional to $dt^2$ which comes from the term $g_{00}dx^0 dx^0$

Comment: @Triatticus ops! I mean $g_{00} = 1$. Thanks.

Comment: Have you worked out $\Gamma^r_{tt}$ for your metric? I can't do the calculation right now, but I bet it isn't zero. That means moving in the time direction will accelerate you in the $r$ direction.

Comment: @JohnRennie Yes I do it in MapleSoft. $\Gamma^r_{tt}  = 0$.

Comment: Why are you setting $g_{00}$? The Schwarzschild metric satisfies $g_{00}=1-\frac{2M}{r}$.

Comment: Sergio, I note your c=1 and _"the origin of gravitation force in GR is mostly due to the curvature of time"_. You might want to look at the second paragraph here: [Einstein digital papers](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/156?highlightText=%22spatially+variable%22).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geodesic equation tells us:

$$ \frac{d^2x^\alpha}{d\tau^2} = -\Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu\nu}u^\mu u^\nu $$

The reason we often say the acceleration is due to the curvature in time is because in everyday life the four-velocity is dominated by the time component i.e. $u^t \gg u^r, u^\theta, u^\phi$. That means to a first approximation we can ignore the terms in $u^tu^a$ and $u^au^b$ ($a$ = $r$, $\theta$ or $\phi$) and consider only the term in $u^tu^t$. Then the only significant Christoffel symbols are $\Gamma^a{}_{tt}$.

But you've chosen a metric for which (in the coordinates being used) $\Gamma^a{}_{tt}=0$. That means you are quite correct that a stationary object will not accelerate in space. Only objects moving in the spatial coordinates will accelerate in space.

This isn't that unusual. The Ellis wormhole has exactly the same property. If you're interested I discuss this in my answer to [How do spatial curvature and temporal curvature differ?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274930/how-do-spatial-curvature-and-temporal-curvature-differ) (actually that is close to a duplicate of this question).

So I guess the answer to your question is that the gravitational acceleration is due to the curvature in time in most circumstances but not all. You have managed to choose one of the exceptional cases.

One last comment, be careful about statements like:

> This metric is only spatially curved

Remember that the Christoffel symbols are not tensors and we can always choose a coordinate system that makes them all zero i.e. the [normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates). In your coordinates it's certainly true that the curvature is spatial, but that's just down to your choice of coordinates and it wouldn't be true of a different coordinate choice.

Comment: As far as I understand, this type of metrics does not cause the initially immobile body to move to $r = 0$, but causes tidal forces in moving bodies. If the body immobile , no forces act on it.

Comment: @Sergio correct! :-)

Comment: Hi John, minor nitpick: I believe you mean "Riemann normal co-ordinates" in your last paragraph.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I did mean [Fermi normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates) though actually just *normal coordinates* is fine.

Comment: They're almost the same, one being a specialization of the other and both will do for this question, but IIRC the Fermi co-ordinates don't have the property you're seeking (wiped-out Christoffels) unless the curve they are adapted to is a geodesic; see Valter's discussion here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/252571/26076. The wiki page doesn't seem to take the more generalized case, discussed in Valter's answer, of Fermi co-ords constructed by Fermi-Walker transport along a non geodesic curve into account.

Comment: PS: This could simply be somewhat a mathematician / physicist thing where groups of people use different words for the same thing to show what camps they belong to. Or, as a Prof of Maths at Monash University, Prof Hans Lausch delighted in saying, when he was unsure of fine distinctions between different mathematics terminolgy, "there really is no difference. The difference arises from a fundamental human need for groups of people to categorize themselves, identify a foe amongst the classes and then to go to war with them".

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance well we were talking about geodesic motion :-)

Answer (score 1):

The geodesic deviation equation is $\ddot{x}^\mu=-\Gamma^\mu_{\nu\rho}\dot{x}^\nu\dot{x}^\rho$, where dots denote derivatives with respect to proper time. Speeds $\ll c$ give $\partial_t\approx\partial_\tau$ and $\dot{x}^j\ll \dot{x}^0$ so $\partial_t^2 x^i\approx -\Gamma^i_{00}$. This recovers Newtonian gravity, and expresses its acceleration in terms of $\Gamma^i_{00}$. You might want to say that's "time curvature", but then there is that pesky spatial index.

Update: in the special case $\Gamma^i_{00}=0$, the approximation becomes  $\partial_t^2 x^i\approx -\Gamma^i_{jk}\beta^j\beta^k$.

Comment: Sergio's point is that $\Gamma^r{}_{tt} = 0$, which indeed it is - I've just checked using Mathematica.

Comment: I think you've missed the point. Sergio has not incorrectly written down the Schwarzschild metric. He is asking what happens if the metric is what he has written down, whatever stress-energy tensor is needed to produce this geometry.

Comment: @JohnRennie I've edited my answer.