# Showing the equivalence principle mathematically

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, geodesics, equivalence-principle

Given the geodesic equation

$$\ddot{x}^{\mu}+\Gamma^{\mu}_{\nu\lambda}\dot{x}^{\nu}\dot{x}^{\lambda} = 0$$
I wish to find a co-ordinate system around a point $x_0$ such that the geodesic equation reduces to
$$\ddot{x}^{\mu} = 0$$ around $x_0$. Can anyone explain with steps how that maybe done? I am unable to find any systematic mathematical derivation of the above anywhere

Comment: [Fermi normal coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_coordinates)

Comment: @JohnRennie It would be very kind of you if you can perhaps demonstrate how this works once here.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252559/2451